# On Canonical Forms for Basic Jordan Matrices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to express the matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  0&-1\\
  1&0
\end{array}\right)$ in Jordan normal form. Decomposing it into its characteristic polynomial, it has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i$. By definition, it would have the canonical form $\Lambda_{\alpha\pm i\beta}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  \alpha&-\beta\\
  \beta&\alpha
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  0&-1\\
  1&0
\end{array}\right)$. However, I have worked through this problem by taking the canonical form as $\Lambda=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  i&0\\
  0&-i
\end{array}\right)$, with $A=T\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  i&0\\
  0&-i
\end{array}\right)T^{-1}$ where $T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  i&i\\
  1&-1
\end{array}\right)$, and surprisingly it works out. The form that I used above is of real eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu: \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  \lambda&0\\
  0&\mu
\end{array}\right)_{\alpha,\beta}$. Can't really figure out why it works when you take $i$ as a real eigenvalue, and instead if you do it the correct way by taking $\Lambda_{\alpha+i\beta}$, the expression you get for $A$ is different – appreciate any pointers I can get, thanks.

Comment: The (usual) Jordan Form of your matrix is the diagonal matrix with entries $\pm i$; this is what you can tranform the matrix to using matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. The (so-called) Real Jordan form of your matrix is just itself; this is the best you can transform it to using matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks for the tip. Is it also correct to say that all matrices in $\Bbb{R}^{2\times2}$ with complex roots will explicitly resemble their Real Jordan forms (the matrix is the Jordan form itself)?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  \alpha&-\beta\\
  \beta&\alpha
\end{array}\right)$ will be similar over $\mathbb{ C}$ to the diagonal matrix with $\alpha \pm i\beta$ on the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

More generally Dunford decomposition (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9composition_de_Dunford) $A=D+N$ with $D$ diagonalisable (or simply diagonal) and $N$ nilpotent is only possible if the minimal polynomial is split.

Here the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$ is irreducible on $\mathbb R$ (so it has no divisors, and minimal polynomial is the same, thus not split).

Jordan normal form is a specialized case of Dunford with an $N$ which has only one upper diagonal of $0$'s and $1$'s, and similarly $A$ cannot be put in this form for real domain.

On $\mathbb C$ the characteristic polynomial is always split $\lambda^2+1=(\lambda-i)(\lambda+1)$ so the matrix you found $D=\operatorname{diag}(i,-i)$ is effectively a Jordan form with $N=0$ (it is diagonalisable).